# low efficient std::move()?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Please take a look at the following code snippet, which seems std::move() is low efficient in this scenario.

```
class A {};

struct B {
    double pi{ 3.14 };
    int    i{ 100 };
    A* pa{ nullptr };
};

int main() {
    B b;
    std::vector<B> vec;
    vec.emplace_back(b);                // 1) without move
    vec.emplace_back(std::move(b));     // 2) with move
    return 0;
}
```

I got the following disassembly in visual studio 2019 [C++ 14, Release]:

```
    vec.emplace_back(b);                // 1) without move
00E511D1  push        eax  
00E511D2  push        0  
00E511D4  lea         ecx,[vec]  
00E511D7  call        std::vector<B,std::allocator<B> >::_Emplace_reallocate<B> (0E512C0h)  
    vec.emplace_back(std::move(b));     // 2) with move
00E511DC  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-18h]  
00E511DF  cmp         eax,dword ptr [ebp-14h]  
00E511E2  je          main+91h (0E511F1h)  
00E511E4  movups      xmm0,xmmword ptr [b]  
00E511E8  movups      xmmword ptr [eax],xmm0  
00E511EB  add         dword ptr [ebp-18h],10h  
00E511EF  jmp         main+9Eh (0E511FEh)  
00E511F1  lea         ecx,[b]  
00E511F4  push        ecx  
00E511F5  push        eax  
00E511F6  lea         ecx,[vec]  
00E511F9  call        std::vector<B,std::allocator<B> >::_Emplace_reallocate<B> (0E512C0h)
```

It's easy to see that the move version takes more unnecessary work. According to the description [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor), the compiler will generate a trivial move constructor for struct B and this trivial move constructor will take a **copy semantic**.

Then my questions are:

1. std::move() is completely redundant for this case.
2. Moreover, if the parameter of std::move() has a trivial move constructor, then std::move() is redundant.
3. if the trivial move constructor performs the same action as the trivial copy constructor, why the compiler generates different disassembly? Actually, this is the most confusing for me.

Comment: It seems your disassembly has also the code of resizing vector. you might try to reserve before.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: An optimising compiler will optimise the body of the main() to "return 0". It's best to use the godbolt.org for this kind of research.

Comment: Nice to know. I tried with godbolt.org and more confused now. for the non-move function, called void std::vector<B,std::allocator<B> >::emplace_back<B &>(B &); for the move-version, called void std::vector<B,std::allocator<B> >::emplace_back<B>(B &&).
Thus, std::move() seems do work because different versions of emplace_back() being called.

Comment: `B&` and `B` are very different, don't expect the same code to run. Also you might want to write your own `move` constructor/assignment etc. if your pointer does anything more interesting.

Comment: Even in these cases I would write std::move, you never know if someone will later add a std::string to B

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. std::move() is completely redundant for this case.

Technically not a question but yes, this is correct.

> 2. Moreover, if the parameter of std::move() has a trivial move constructor, then std::move() is redundant.

Same as above.

> 3. if the trivial move constructor performs the same action as the trivial copy constructor, why the compiler generates different disassembly?

Possibly because you call the function `std::move` in one but not the other.

It doesn't have to produce different assembly however since the observable behaviour is identical. My compiler produces identical assembly.

Comment: I tried with goldbolt.org suggested by @bobah and the disassembly is different. for the non-move function, called void std::vector<B,std::allocator<B> >::emplace_back<B &>(B &); for the move-version, called void std::vector<B,std::allocator<B> >::emplace_back<B>(B &&). Thus, std::move() seems do work because different versions of emplace_back() being called.

Comment: @fetag If you want to share information about this, you could share a godbolt link. At the moment I don't know exactly what compiler version you used or how to reproduce what you saw.

Comment: @Useless many thanks! here is it: https://godbolt.org/z/zczGYG

Comment: @fetag OK, that's with no optimization. Not even the call to `std::move` is inlined. If you turn on any optimization at all, the picture is very different and much less clear.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would like to make a summary of this question.

1. if the move constructor is trivial (generated by the compiler), then std::move() only takes a bitwise copy. Which means vec.emplace_back(std::move(b)) is equivalent to vec.emplace_back(b).
2. following is another better example to show the difference. We try to construct both members _x and _y with move semantic. Since X has a user-declared move ctor but Y hasn't, X's move ctor gets called, and Y's copy ctor gets called.

```
class X {
public:
    X() { cout << "X()" << endl; }
    X(X const&) { cout << "X(X const&)" << endl; }
    X(X&&) noexcept { cout << "X(X&&)" << endl; }
};

class Y {
public:
    Y() { cout << "Y()" << endl; }
    Y(Y const&) { cout << "Y(Y const&)" << endl; }
};

struct Box {
    Box(X&& x, Y&& y) : _x(std::move(x)), _y(std::move(y)) {}
    X _x;
    Y _y;
};

int main() {
    X x;
    Y y;
    Box bb(std::move(x), std::move(y));
    return 0;
}

/*
output:
X()
Y()
X(X&&)
Y(Y const&)
*/
```